# Dockerfile for sprin-boot application fails to build image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I generated a Dockerfile for my `spring-boot` application, which is called `demo-api`. This is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
COPY target/demo_api*.jar ./demo_api.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Duser.timezone=GMT -jar /demo_api.jar
EXPOSE 8080
```

However when I run `docker build .` I get the following error message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  84.05MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:11-slim
 ---> 724512274dbb
Step 2/4 : COPY target/demo_api*.jar ./demo_api.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

Does anyone understand why I get this error and how I could fix it? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the application (and probably the jar file) is called `demo-api' but you are using underscore in the Docker file.

Comment: im sorry but how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Based on what you said in the question
`...which is called demo-api.` but your Docker file uses `COPY target/demo_api*.jar ./demo_api.jar`

Answer (score 0):

remove * in demo_api.jar target folder which you are specifying.